# Can I use a GWT Library in Dart?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, dart

I want to migrate to Dart but I am not sure if it is mature enough.

**Is it possible to use a library written in GWT in Dart?**

Answer (score 2):

No.

Except if your GWT library is exported in JS. In that case you can use it as any other Js library with [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-js).